# Test each switch/case with jUnit

Tags: java, unit-testing

I'm attempting to test each switch/case block with jUnit, but I'm not sure how to have each TestCase correspond to different switch/cases.

I currently have the following code in MenuTest.java:

```
package com.cw.hospital.test;

import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.Assert;
import com.cw.hospital.Menu;

public class MenuTest {


    Menu MainMenu;

    public MenuTest() {
        super();
        MainMenu = new Menu();
    }


    @Test
    public void Case1() {

    }

    @Test
    public void Case2() {

    } 

    @Test
    public void Case3() {

    }


}
```

My Menu class (the class im testing) has a main() method. Inside that method i'm reading the users input, and then switching that input.

How would I send different input from the Test class to the Menu?

Comment: How does your main() method read the user's input?

Answer (score 0):

Create an instance of the class in the setup method (annotated with @Before) and pass the arguments to the main method. The key here is what you want to test. If you show your class under test I can update the answer with more hints.

EDIT: if you really want to unit test your main method, you'll have to mock your Flight class. If the method called in the Flight class returns something, you'll have to tell the mock framework to return something accordingly.

Comment: Well firstly, I'm printing a menu to the user. The user then enters which menu item (1, 2, 3, 4...). That input is then switch()ed. And case "1": for example just calls a method Flight.listPassengers();. The test for that would just be if the output matched my expected output (which i'd have to hard code into the testing method).

Comment: Other cases require further input from the user though. Case 2 requires the user to enter new Flight data for example.

Answer (score 0):

It is easier to test stuff if you separate things like I/O stuff and input consumption.  By this I mean have the I/O stuff somewhere (perhaps in your main) then create a method that takes the input as a parameter (perhaps a String).

Then just call the consumption method from your JUnit tests with parameter values that force the path in the switch statement.  For example:

```
[in the class under test]
void methodName()
{
  String theInput;
  ... perform I/O and populate "theInput"
  consume(theInput);
}

void consume(final String input)
{
  switch (someting based on input)
  {
     ...
  }
}


[in your junit]
@Test
testConditionOne()
{
  consume("force condition one");
}

@Test
testConditionTwo()
{
 consume("force condition two");
}

... etc.
```

Answer (score 0):

mocking user input can be done with System.setIn(); and you can pass a PipedInputStream where you pass the input cases ytou want to test

```
public class MenuTest {

    OutputStream stdIn;
    InputStream stdOut;
    Menu MainMenu;

    public MenuTest() {
        super();

        PipedInputStream in = new PipedInputStream();
        stdIn = new PipedOutputStream(in);
        System.setIn(in);

        PipedOutputStream out = new PipedInputStream();
        stdOut = new PipedInputStream(out);
        System.setOut(out);

        MainMenu = new Menu();
    }

    //...


}
```

you'll want to use a separate thread to pass the input as the main method will block until it can read something

a similar thing can be done to capture the System.out output

Comment: How would you go about grabbing the Output then? 
I could use an assert then to check the Output against some test data.

Comment: @Nick copy/past and `s/in/out/` and `s/out/in/`